Get the hostname of a jenkins slave node having a particular label with REST
I am attempting to retrieve hostnames of jenkins nodes having a label via the jenkins REST API.
I can get the names of the nodes I care about via the following:
curl --silent https://jenkins.example.tld/computer/api/json | jq '.computer[] | select(.assignedLabels[].name=="my_label")'

Among the results are an item called displayName, which appears to be the only identifying information for the node.  It is not a hostname though.
I have tried getting the node information with this:
curl --silent 'https://jenkins.example.tld/computer/my_display_name/api/json'

but it only returns the same information I already have using the previous query.  How can I query the Jenkins REST API to convert the displayName to an actual hostname/IP address?
